# Displaying results for fixed values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having difficulty in solving the below problem:

I have a table which contains the shopid, date, hour, category and sales amount.

```
shopid   date     hour      category  amount
    ------------------------------------
    1    date1    7          food       10
    1    date1    8          food       15
    1    date1    10         misc.      5
    2    date1    7          food       6
    ...................................
```

I am trying to calculate the total sales amount in each hour by food category and display like the following:

```
shopid  category     hour        amount
    ------------------------------------
    1       food      6             0
    1       food      7             5
    1       food      8             20
    2       food      9             40
    ...................................
```

The shops' opening hours are 6 am -10 pm. So for each hour, there might be any sales or not. I was able to perform the hourly summation. But I am unable to display zero and the time when there are no sales at a particular time (e.g. 6 am or any other time between the opening hours) for each sale category.

Comment: you will have to create  a new table with shopid, category and hour (6 to 22) and then join with your table. Since you are not having date apply filter on that

Comment: @ShamsurRahimHemel . . . Your results don't make sense.  If you want summaries by category and  hour, why do the results have `shopid`?  If you want results by shop, category, and hour, where are the rows with 0 values?

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join against a list of hours:

```
select t.shopid, t.category. g.hour, sum(t.amount)
from generate_series(6,22) as g(hour)
  left join the_table t on t.hour = g.hour
group by t.shopid, t.category, g.hour
order by t.shopid, t.category, g.hour;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to calculate the total sales amount in each hour by food category.

This makes sense, but it doesn't make sense to include the `shopid` in the results.

To do this, you need to generate the rows -- which are all hours and food categories.  Then bring in the actual results  using `left join`:

```
select c.category. g.hour, coalesce(sum(s.amount), 0)
from generate_series(6, 22) g(hour) cross join
     (select distinct category from sales) c left join
     sales s
     on s.hour = g.hour and s.category = c.category
group by c.category, g.hour
order by c.category, g.hour;
```

If you want results by shop/category/hour, then you can use the same idea:

```
select sh.shopid, c.category. g.hour,
       coalesce(sum(s.amount), 0)
from generate_series(6, 22) g(hour) cross join
     (select distinct category from sales) c cross join
     (select distinct shopid from sales) sh left join
     sales s
     on s.shopid = sh.shopid and
        s.hour = g.hour and
        s.category = c.category
group by sh.shopid, c.category, g.hour
order by sh.shopid, c.category, g.hour;
```